# How to upgrade Appium 1.5.3 to Appium 1.8.1

Tags: appium

I have tried with command:

```
npm -install -g appium@1.6
```

but when I restart Appium, it is still in 1.5.3 version.

Comment: do you restart appium from console/terminal or the gui app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two different types of appium tool avaliable

1. Appium GUI
2. Appium command tool

It seems you updated to the command tool of appium and launch the appium GUI then you are checking the version.

Till now there is no GUI for appium1.6.

If you are checking command tool then there is some issue, you need to uninstall and install appium.

Answer (score 19):

You can do

```
1. npm uninstall -g appium 
2. npm install -g appium@1.8.1 
3. appium -v
```

*@is for specific version*

Appium 1.8.1

Comment: This didn't worked in my case. I am still able to see the previous version only

Answer (score 6):

If you have an old version of Appium server than you can update it without uninstalling it by executing following command in terminal or command prompt

```
npm -g update appium
```

This will update your Appium version to the latest version.

In case you want to update to a specific version than execute the following command:

```
npm update -g appium@1.6
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had similar issues upgrading to a higher version of appium.

This has worked for me whenever I have problem with appium

```
npm uninstall -g appium
npm cache clean --force
```

Then do,

```
npm install -g appium@1.6
```

or

```
npm install -g appium
```

To get the latest version of appium

Answer (score 1):

You can run below command in terminal to install appium 1.6

```
npm install appium
```

For this you need node.js to be installed in your machine
You can specify the version of the appium to be installed by using below command

```
npm install appium 1.6.3
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
npm install appium -g
```

you should get the latest stable version.

But if you are looking to install a specific beta, use following command from terminal:

```
npm install -g appium@1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out without -g, it should work without it. Also your version is wrong, use that one:

npm -install appium@1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
npm install appium -g
```

It by default installed the latest.

Answer (score -2):

Try this command

npm install -g appium@1.6.0

Comment: please explain further